# Connect Macbook Air hard drive to other PC

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, data-transfer

My friend spilled Apple Cider on her Macbook Air (a1466) and I am trying to see if there is a way to connect the Hard drive to a PC so I can do the data recovery.
Is there any connector that I can use any any other tips? My plan is to just plug it in and mount it on Linux and do a transfer. I have an Ubuntu desktop that can do the work and plenty of space.

Answer (score 0):

This might go on the Apple site (http://apple.stackexchange.com), but I'll give it a shot:

From what I read, the connector is [a variant of PCIe and mSATA](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47479/what-is-the-connector-used-by-the-mbas-sata-drive), so you'll probably need an identical MacBook Air (because different models have different connectors, as stated [here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/macbook-air-faq/macbook-air-mid-2012-how-to-replace-upgrade-ssd-storage.html)) to read your friend's disk. The guys at iFixit have [a guide for the removal process.](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2012+Solid-State+Drive+Replacement/10961)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Aura Pro. It is a usb connector specifically for the mac book air solid state drives.

http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSDAP2A6K120/